# SQL Server expensive nested loops join and lazy table spool

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, query-performance

I am trying to tune the below query which takes 15-16 seconds no matter what value is passed in as a parameter, the query is:

```
select distinct d.documentpath as path, d.documentname as name, d.datecreated as created, pc.DateProcessed
from datagatheringruntime dgr 
 inner join processentitymapping pem on pem.entityid = dgr.entityid 
 inner join document d on d.entityid = pem.entityid or d.unitofworkid = pem.processid
 left join PendingCorrespondence pc on pc.PendingCorrespondenceId = d.PendingCorrespondenceId
 where rootid = @P0 and dgr.name in('cust_pn', 'case_pn')
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

I have updated the statistics for all the tables touched by the query (excluding the `DataGatheringRuntime` table which is quite big at ~`100GB`) and have tried re-factoring the query using a `CTE` but get the same execution plan and need some assistance.

The actual execution plan can be found here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByUVIqlFE

It's clear from the execution plan that the problem lies with the outer input on the `nested loop join` specifically with the `lazy table spool` following the `scan` of the non-clustered `IX_Camunda_1` index on the `Document` table but I have no idea how to tackle that issue and would appreciate any guidance.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide DDL of these tables. I am not sure if this is relevant here but, have you tried using join options like inner loop join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I would try removing the `OR` clause in the join between `document` and `processingentitymapping`**

You could do that with `UNION`

```
SELECT distinct d.documentpath as path, d.documentname as name, d.datecreated as created, pc.DateProcessed
FROM datagatheringruntime dgr 
INNER JOIN processentitymapping pem on pem.entityid = dgr.entityid 
INNER JOIN document d on d.entityid = pem.entityid 
LEFT JOIN PendingCorrespondence pc on pc.PendingCorrespondenceId = d.PendingCorrespondenceId
WHERE rootid = @P0 and dgr.name in('cust_pn', 'case_pn')
UNION
SELECT distinct d.documentpath as path, d.documentname as name, d.datecreated as created, pc.DateProcessed
FROM datagatheringruntime dgr 
INNER JOIN processentitymapping pem on pem.entityid = dgr.entityid 
INNER JOIN document d on d.unitofworkid = pem.processid
LEFT JOIN PendingCorrespondence pc on pc.PendingCorrespondenceId = d.PendingCorrespondenceId
WHERE rootid = @P0 and dgr.name in('cust_pn', 'case_pn')
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

The reason being that the table spool is feeding the `NESTED LOOPS` operator 
[image]

And on this nested loops operator is the `OR` predicate.
[image]

Filtering out until we have 9 rows remaining.

Changing the `OR` to a `UNION` should remove the spool, you might have to look into indexing after removing the `OR`.

**Indexes that could improve performance after rewriting with `UNION`**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_EntityId
on document(EntityId)
INCLUDE(DocumentPath, DocumentName, DateCreated, PendingCorrespondenceId);

CREATE INDEX IX_UnitOfWorkId
on document(UnitOfWorkId)
INCLUDE(DocumentPath, DocumentName, DateCreated, PendingCorrespondenceId);
```

[See here](http://www.sqlnuggets.com/blog/performance-problem-when-using-or-in-a-join/) for another example on this

Comment: thank you so much for that, the query now executes in under one second (without any index changes).  Thanks for posting that link too, you've helped me big time and I've learned something new, much appreciated!

Comment: @Fza Awesome, good to hear :). No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing `DataGatheringRuntime table which is quite big at ~100GB)` mutiples times
process it single time by putting them in `#temp` table <s>or `CTE`</s>

Then remove `Distinct`. If there is duplicate data then find the reason behind duplicate data 
and remove duplicate data by writing correct query.

What is the purpose of `Distinct` and `UNION` in same query ?

```
Create table #temp(entityid int,processid int)
select pem.entityid,pem.processid
from datagatheringruntime dgr 
 inner join processentitymapping pem on pem.entityid = dgr.entityid 
 where rootid = @P0 and dgr.name in('cust_pn', 'case_pn')
 --OPTION(RECOMPILE)

 select d.documentpath as path, d.documentname as name, d.datecreated as created, pc.DateProcessed
from document d
left join PendingCorrespondence pc on pc.PendingCorrespondenceId = d.PendingCorrespondenceId
 where exists(select 1 from  #temp pem where  d.entityid = pem.entityid )

 UNION ALL

 select d.documentpath as path, d.documentname as name, d.datecreated as created, pc.DateProcessed
from document d
left join PendingCorrespondence pc on pc.PendingCorrespondenceId = d.PendingCorrespondenceId
 where exists(select 1 from  #temp pem where  d.unitofworkid = pem.processid )
```

Comment: CTEs don't persist data.